# Failing to pass data from view to the Action by Html.BeginForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am very new at asp.net mvc, so the reason behind my failure might be something basic as well, but I can't seem to find it after nearly a days work now.

What I am trying to do is to get the edited Model from the Index view and pass it to a second action which does not have view and returns return `RedirectToAction("Index")`  in the related controller. In `OrdersItemsController` my Action is as the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MarkedShipped(IEnumerable<orders_items> orderItems)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var item in orderItems)
        {
            unitOfWork.GenericRepository<orders_items>().Update(item);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And in the Index.cshtml which is in OrdersItems folder in the Views, what I did is as following:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.DataAccess.orders_items>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MarkedShipped", "OrdersItems", new { orderItems = Model }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.quantity)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.itemprice)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.trackingnumber)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemprice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.trackingnumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.itemid })
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="MarkShipped" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My problem is, I am not able to get the Model from the view with orderItems parameter, I am not sure if this is the right "syntax" for what I am trying to accomplish; but what I get for `orderItems` when the action is called is a List of `orders_items` with `Count = 0` not a null value.

I have also checked if there is an application level exception, but got no exception from `Application_Error` in `Global.asax`

I am stuck for a day now so If anyone can point me a direction on how to pass the Model (or "the edited data") to the action for me to update the db, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: put FormMethod.Post in your BeginForm parameters.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop - it generates duplicate `name` attributes without indexers necessary for binding to a collection and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html. You need to use a `for` loop (or a custom `EditorTemplate` for the typeof your model). Your model needs to be `IList<T>` and then `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].trackingnumber) ...}`

Comment: And you cannot add your model as a route parameter - it is a collection which means binding will fail (look at the html your generating to understand). And in any case, what would be the point of add the original model as a route parameter anyway (you already know what it is in the server).

Comment: I thought the edited Model was routed as a parameter because the EditorFor helpers are directly linked with the given property, what I understood was : it is changing the item of the Model's property directly. So when passing the Model I thought I passed the updated collection.

Comment: @Neel I tried it as well but it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you cannot add a model which is a collection (or a model which contains a property which is a complex object or collection) to a forms route parameters. Internally the helper calls the `.ToString()` method and if you inspect the html generated for your form tag you will see something like

```
<form action=OrdersItems/MarkedShipped?orderItems=System.Collection.Generic.......
```

and binding will fail since you collection cannot be bound to a string. Even if it did work, it would be rather pointless because it would just post back the original values of the model.

Next, you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls. Again if you inspect the html your generating you will see that the `EditorFor()` method is generating inputs with duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which do not have the necessary indexers to bind to a collection when you post.  You need to use either a `for` loop of a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `orders_items`

Using a `for` loop means that your model must implement `IList<T>` and the view needs to be

```
@model IList<Hochanda.CraftsHobbiesAndArts.DataAccess.orders_items>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) // only necessary to add the controller and action if they differ from the GET method
{
  ....
  @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].quantity)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].trackingnumber)
  }
  ....
}
```

Using an `EditorTemplate`, create a partial in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/orders_items.cshtml` (note the name of the file must match the name of the class)

```
@model Hochanda.CraftsHobbiesAndArts.DataAccess.orders_items
<tr>
  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.quantity)</td>
  ....
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.trackingnumber)</td>
  ....
</tr>
```

and then in the main view (you can use `IEnumerable<T>`)

```
@model IEnumerable<Hochanda.CraftsHobbiesAndArts.DataAccess.orders_items>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      ....
    <thead>
    <tbody>
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
    </tbody>
  </table>
  ....
}
```

The `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and will generate one row for each item in you collection based on the html in the `EditorTemplate`

In both cases, it you inspect the html you will now see the correct name attributes necessary for you model to bind when you post

```
<input type="text" name="[0].trackingnumber" ... />
<input type="text" name="[1].trackingnumber" ... />
<input type="text" name="[3].trackingnumber" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I implemented like you explained and it works perfectly as expected. You've been very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try For instead of foreach here.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemprice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.trackingnumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.itemid })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Check this :- http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: I implemented this, I removed the foreach and added a for loop, but this doesn't help me with passing the data back to the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
 for (int i = 0; i < @ViewBag.Persons; i++)
  {

    <li>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fullname,new { @id = "FullnameLabel" + @i })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Fullname, new { @id = "Fullname" + @i })
                </td>

            </tr>
```

In this way each html element gets its own unique id and its possible to retrieve the information back from them individually. You can use for or Foreach. Just make sure that your razor iterator is functioning. You can view the element ids in the source to see if it is working.

Comment: You CANNOT use a `foreach` loop, and the html helpers will generate unique `id` attributes inside a `for` loop so overriding it is pointless. In any case the `id` attributes have nothing to do with it - its thevalues of the `name` and `value` attributes which are posted back to the controller

Comment: Im generating html blocks dynamically with razor. If you dont force specify the ids (like i have done) then you only get the values typed in the first block when looking at your model in the controller.

Comment: You need to learn some basics of MVC. The correct usage is as as per my first comment to the question - i.e  `@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].trackingnumber)` You code is completely wrong and wont work.