# ASP.NET MVC4 IEnumerable empty on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have read several answers on this issue but despite this, it would appear I have developed code blindness.

I have the following view model:

```
public class IndividualProductVm
{
    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
    public ProductSummary ProductSummary { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<ProductSimpleResponse> ProductSimpleResponse { get; set; }
}
```

This is then passed into a view and then a partial view:

```
@model Websites.ViewModels.IndividualProductVm @{ ViewBag.Title = "Edit"; }

<h2>Edit</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "form", id = "mainForm" })) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken() @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Products.Id) @Html.HiddenFor(model
=> model.ProductSummary.SupplierId) Html.RenderPartial("_IndividualProduct", Model);


<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</div>

}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new { id = Model.ProductSummary.SupplierId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</div>

@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }

@model Websites.ViewModels.IndividualProductVm

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products.ProductCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Products.ProductCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products.ProductDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Products.ProductDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Present
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.ProductSimpleResponse)
    {
        <tr>

            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SupplierId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Present)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

However, when I enter the edit post, my viewmodel is null for the `IEnumerable<ProductSimpleResponse>` but fine for the other two classes.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(IndividualProductVm model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ProductSummary.SupplierId });
        }

        return View(model.Products);
    }
```

If someone can explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. You need a `for` loop (the model must be `IList<T>` or custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `ProductSvhcSimpleResponse`, Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562284/failing-to-pass-data-from-view-to-the-action-by-html-beginform/31576073#31576073) for a detailed explanation

Comment: Please check with List<t> replace by IEnumerable<t>

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I was adamant that I had tried to implement the for solution but without success. However, post lunch, clear head and another  attempt and that's got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your property name is ProductSimpleResponse, alhtough the type is ProductSvhcSimpleResponse, so to iterate through it  you should have.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProductSimpleResponse)
```

NOT

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ProductSvhcSimpleResponse)
```

Comment: Hi Begur - That was me being a copy and paste idiot. I will edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

use List because

IEnumerable is suitable just for iterate through collection and you can not modify (Add or Remove) data IEnumerable bring ALL data from server to client then filter them, assume that you have a lot of records so IEnumerable puts overhead on your memory.

```
public class IndividualProductVm
{
    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
    public ProductSummary ProductSummary { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductSvhcSimpleResponse> ProductSimpleResponse { get; set; }
}
```

[More help click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832189/List-vs-IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable-vs-ICollection-v)

Comment: Nonsense. All OP is doing is iterating the collection, not adding or removing! And `List<T>` is (implements) `IEnumerable<T>`. Its `List<T>` that add extra ovehead!

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - Thank you for give me right way but see this link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832189/List-vs-IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable-vs-ICollection-v

Comment: What about that link? Nothing in it is related to OP's issue. However you should read the link I gave in my comment to the question to understand what OP's issue is and how to solve it.